# SQL conditional sum of nutritional values

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, sum

I have a simple enough table like this.

```
NutritionID | Value  
----------------------
1           |    10   
2           |    11  
3           |    12  
1           |    N      
1           |    Tr    
1           |    NULL
```

**Expected result**

```
NutritionID   | Value  
----------------------
 1            |   N   
 2            |   11  
 3            |   12
```

I need to get the sum for each NutritionID. But there are rules that determine the final value.
For example,

1. N + N = N
2. N + Tr = N
3. N + a value = N
4. Tr + a value = value
5. Tr + NULL = Tr
6. NULL + 0 = 0

**Solution in mind**

1. Create a cursor for NutritionID
2. keep the running sum in a variable
3. implement the above rules in if/else statements

**problem**

Is there a better way to get the sum efficiently and with a non-cursor solution? perhaps using case statements?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is unclear. In which order are the rows processed? What's the expected result?

Comment: Edited the question. Simply I need the sum for each NutritionID.

Comment: Where is your code so we can help you fix it?

Comment: In which order should we process the rows? Remember that tables do not have inherent row ordering. Let's assume we process them in the order you show (I don't know how, but let's assume so for a sec): we'll need to add `10` + `N`... but this rule does not exist; I can only see `N` + `10`... This is still quite unclear.

Comment: @TheImpaler The above table is a temporary table in a stored procedure. So it doesn't have an order I am afraid. If I have a running sum variable in the cursor I can implement the rules. For Example, if the running sum in 10 and the new value is N, the new running sum would be N. Hope it clarifies the problem.

Comment: @nicomp My proposed solution is given under 'Solution in mind'. I am supposed to find the best solution before implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be mixing strings and numeric values in the same column - and your computation rules are quite convoluted.

I think that you can do what you want with conditional logic:

```
select
    nutritionID,
    case 
        when max(value = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 
            then 'N'
        when sum(try_cast(value as int)) is not null
            then cast(sum(try_cast(value as int)) as varchar(10))
        when max(value = 'Tr' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 
            then 'Tr'
    end
from mytable
group by nutritionID
```

Basically this gives priority to `'N'`, then to a non-`null` sum of integer values, then to `Tr`, and yields `null` if none of these conditions match.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the solution. Yes, the rules are very complex and it is a matter of precedence.